# some images are not loading in react app even they exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I'm working on a ReactJs app. Everything works fine in development. When I make a build using `npm run build` and test it, some images on a page are shown, and some images are simply not found. I can see that the user avatar image is shown, but all other images are not shown. I inspected the code in a browser and checked the `src` of the image. The path is good, and the image is also available in `./static/media/card-1.7a6bc100.jpg` but not showing on the page. Then I inspected the code of the user avatar image, `src` looks similar, and that image is working fine. I'm not sure why it's behaving like this. Below is what my source code looks like.

```js
import marc from "assets/img/faces/marc.jpg";
```

And then my `img` tag looks like:

```js
<img src={marc} className={imgStyle} alt="..." />
```

It always spits out `...` dots, which means the image is not loaded, but the image is available there, and the path is also perfect when I inspect this image in a browser. Can anyone help me understand why it is doing this on production? It's been hours while working on this, but I haven't found any solution.

Comment: did you find any solution for it . I am also facing similar problem. The path in the build server seems different. It is automatically coming like sitename/component/static/media/image rather than sitename/static/..

Comment: its seems like baseurl and context path issue

Comment: @user:4227525 have you got some resolution?

Comment: Can you provide a simple reproduction of your issue?

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like a cache issue (works fine in dev, not in production) but obviously only if it's only newer or recently changed images that aren't displaying as expected.

Comment: if your _images_ in **public** folder, you can access those img like this `src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "img/example.jpg"}`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `create-react-app`, assets will also need to be served inside `src`. You should also reference the image using relative path, not absolute path. For example:

image is under `src/assets/img/faces`

your code is under `src/some-folder/your-code.js`

```js
// your-code.js
import marc from "../assets/img/faces/marc.jpg";
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me. As I mentioned in question, some images are loading and some are simply dont. Even image exists at same path but does not load. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but solved it by importing images instead of using exact path on src

```
<img src="src/assets/Waving.gif" alt="" />
```

**this way**

```
import Waving from "../assets/Waving.gif"
<img src={Waving}  alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your images in `public/images/` folder and use like this

```
<img src="/images/logo.png" className={imgStyle} alt="Logo" />
```

Comment: but I don't think that's the correct way. not sure. let me try

Comment: That's one of the ways. This is how `create-react-app` boilerplate does

Answer (score 0):

Place your static assets within the `./public` folder. For example, if you have an image called `image-123.png`, move it to the `./public` folder.

You can then access the image in your HTML code like this:

```html
<img src="/image-123.png" alt="logo123" />
```

Feel free to organize your assets further by creating sub-folders within the `./public` directory. For instance, you can create a folder like `./public/assets/` and access the image as follows:

```html
<img src="/assets/image-123.png" alt="logo123" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is only about missing the first slash `/` at the first of the import value. The compiler didn't find the right path of the image because the path is invalid. Instead of using this

```js
import marc from 'assets/img/faces/marc.jpg';
```

then try this

```
import marc from '/assets/img/faces/marc.jpg';
```

Full code: https://playcode.io/1589865

Full demo: https://1589865.playcode.io